# Iterating trough Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a csv file "players.csv" with attributes of players "Name, Age, Nationality, Overall, Potential, **Club, Value** ...".

My task is to sum up the value of all clubs by adding all their players value together.

So far I get the desired outcome with the following solution. My problem is that my solution takes a very long time to process, because of the two for loops.

Is there any more efficient way to solve the problem? (Dataframe has 14700 players)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'

# Load the data with only the Club Name and Value of the player
df = pd.read_csv('./players.csv',usecols=['Club','Value'])

# Create new List where the Club Value will be shown
# Drop all duplicates of Clubs. Now we have a Dataframe with all the available Clubs inside
# Futhermore Drop the column 'Value' and add 'Club_Value'
df_Clubs = df.drop_duplicates('Club').drop('Value',axis=1)
df_Clubs['Club_Value']=0

df = df.sort_values(by=["Club"])

#Iterating trough the players Dataframe and get the row we are in and the Value of that row
for rowdf, valuedf in df.iterrows():
    #Iterating trough the new Dataframe with only the unique Clubs
    for row, value in df_Clubs.iterrows():
        if valuedf["Club"] == value["Club"]:
            #When the Club of the Player matches with the Unique Clubs Dataframe,
            #we asign the Value of the Player to the club Value
            ValueClub_old = df_Clubs["Club_Value"][row]
            ValuePlayer = df["Value"][rowdf]
            ValueClub_new = ValueClub_old + ValuePlayer
            df_Clubs["Club_Value"][row] = ValueClub_new

# save the new dataframe
df_Clubs.to_csv(r'Players_Value.csv', index = False)
df.head()
print(df_Clubs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use groupby on clubs and sum.

```
df_new=df.groupby(['Club'])['Value'].sum().reset_index()
```